# CircleCI config: Missing property "docker" in VSCode

Tags: circleci, circleci-workflows

I have CircleCI workflow, it has defined executor and number of jobs using that executor:

```
version: 2.1

executors:
  circleci-aws-build-agent:
    docker:
      - image: kagarlickij/circleci-aws-build-agent:latest
    working_directory: ~/project

jobs:
  checkout:
    executor: circleci-aws-build-agent
    steps:
      - checkout
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ~/
          paths:
            - project

  set_aws_config:
    executor: circleci-aws-build-agent
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/
      - run:
          name: Set AWS credentials
          command: bash aws-configure.sh
```

It works as expected but in VSCode I see errors:
[image]

Any ideas how it could be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your yml, the [issue is with Schemastore](https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/issues/627), which VSCode uses.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are missing the `docker` block which defines the default container image for the job. A valid block would be:

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
    - image: node:10
    steps:
    - checkout
```

If you have several jobs that use the same image, you can define a variable:

```
var_1: &job_defaults
  docker:
  - image: node:10

jobs:
  build:
    <<: *job_defaults
    steps:
    - checkout 
  deploy:
    <<: *job_defaults
    steps:
    - checkout
```

Documentation: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#docker--machine--macosexecutor

Comment: @21217070AB14 answer above is correct. At the time of my answer, I was unaware of "executors" for CircleCI. I'll leave my answer for others who stumble across this; but please refer to the linked GitHub issue regarding the broken support for executors.